# How to inflate a Fragment (List) that was created by the Android studio wizard in an Activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-listfragment

In Android Studio (v.4.0.1) File -> New -> Fragment -> Fragment (List)
creates a Dummy List with all components needed (Adapter, XMLs etc). When leaving the default names given by the wizard it creates these xml files :

fragment_item_list.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="de.afu.development.test.afu_portfolio_searcher_app_test.ItemFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context=".ItemFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item" />
```

and fragment_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />
```

I can´t figure out how to inflate the Fragment in my Activity, I tried with :

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.list, new ItemFragment()).commit();
```

or

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.list, ItemFragment.newInstance(1)).commit();
```

where I know the error lies within 'R.id.list' because I get the following stacktrace error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f....:id/list) for fragment ItemFragment ...
```

'R.id.list' is the ID given to the RecyclerView by the wizard.

I also tried wrapping fragment_item_list.xml and fragment_item.xml into a FrameLayout and calling R.id.blabla from within the Framelayout, I saw this in other answers, but that did not work either.

So how do I inflate that Wizard created Fragment (List) in my Activity and why does my approach not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have some `ViewGroup` in your `Activity`s layout, e.g. `RelativeLayout`, which would be container for your `Fragment`. You are setting `RecyclerView` as container, this wont work as this item isn't proper container and isn't added to `Activity` at all (so `No view found for id` in `Exception`). `RecyclerView` is a part of `Fragment`s layout (after creating and adding), in which you have implemented `Adapter`. Will be available when `Fragment` will run and you are crashing on line which tries to add `Fragment`

`.add(R.id.list, new ItemFragment())` - replace `R.id.list` with your container id inflated in `Activity` (layout passed to `setContentView`)

Comment: ok this is not exactly the answer but it helped so I'll accept it. Got it working with adding an xml fragment element to my main xml with reference (android:name=)to the Fragment Java Class

Comment: you've never said that you need only one fixed `Fragment` attached once for whole time... ;) you've used `FragmentTransaction`, so I assumed that you need some "dynamic" way for exchanging `Fragment`s during runtime. most important that `Fragment` is working for you now :) good luck!